# Ignore code in different iterations of loop

Tags: r

I have six lines of code that all do some preprocessing on a dataset. Now I want to find out which combination of them works best. On top of that, another preprocessing takes a numerical parameter (removeSparseTerms()), so that has to be combined too.

What I want to do is run a for loop or something similar to evaluate all possible combinations:

```
for(i in seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1)){
  tm_map(data, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  tm_map(....)
  tm_map(....)
  tm_map(....)
  tm_map(....)
  tm_map(....)

  removeSparseTerm(data, i)

  <evaluation>
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how I can make it skip lines of code, i.e. on the first iteration it should run none of the tm_map(), on the second the first, etc. This should also include the combinations of different tm_map lines. 
What's the best way to do this? If-statements seem annoyingly long to write.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... all steps are needed for pre-processing, or any of them would do, or you believe some combination of them could work, but you're not sure, and any combination may work? also, what do you mean by "works best". If you mean, works fastest, then probably using the `bench` package may help, in particular the `press` function if you're trying with different parameters http://bench.r-lib.org/reference/press.html

Comment: all steps are optional, any combination works. "works best" is the result of the <evaluation> further down the code. I can determine that with the same code in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 6 functions and you want to run all possible combinations of them, then there will be 2^6 = 64 possible combinations. These are equivalent to the numbers 0-63 represented as 6-bit binary numbers, where `000000` is zero and `111111` is 63. So all you need to do to enumerate all possibilities is assign each function a flag bit (1 to 6), then loop from 0 to 63, and conditionally run each function according to whether its flag bit is present. The following little helper function will make this easier:

```r
check_bit <- function(x, n_bit) !(as.numeric(as.raw(2^(n_bit - 1)) & as.raw(x)) == 0)
```

Let's see an example of how to run all combinations of a group of functions using this:

```r
  for(j in 0:63){
    if(check_bit(j, 1)) cat("a")
    if(check_bit(j, 2)) cat("b")
    if(check_bit(j, 3)) cat("c")
    if(check_bit(j, 4)) cat("d")
    if(check_bit(j, 5)) cat("e")
    if(check_bit(j, 6)) cat("f")
    cat("\n")
  }
#> 
#> a
#> b
#> ab
#> c
#> ac
#> bc
#> abc
#> d
#> ad
#> bd
#> abd
#> cd
#> acd
#> bcd
#> abcd
#> e
#> ae
#> be
#> abe
#> ce
#> ace
#> bce
#> abce
#> de
#> ade
#> bde
#> abde
#> cde
#> acde
#> bcde
#> abcde
#> f
#> af
#> bf
#> abf
#> cf
#> acf
#> bcf
#> abcf
#> df
#> adf
#> bdf
#> abdf
#> cdf
#> acdf
#> bcdf
#> abcdf
#> ef
#> aef
#> bef
#> abef
#> cef
#> acef
#> bcef
#> abcef
#> def
#> adef
#> bdef
#> abdef
#> cdef
#> acdef
#> bcdef
#> abcdef
```

So your final loop will look something like this:

```
for(i in seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1)){
  for(j in 0:63){
    if(check_bit(j, 1)) tm_map(data, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
    if(check_bit(j, 2)) tm_map(....)
    if(check_bit(j, 3)) tm_map(....)
    if(check_bit(j, 4)) tm_map(....)
    if(check_bit(j, 5)) tm_map(....)
    if(check_bit(j, 6)) tm_map(....)

    removeSparseTerm(data, i)

    <evaluation>
  }
}
```